# SQL Server - Stored Procedure query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I need some help with dDatabase development.

I have 2 million records in my primary table. My stored procedure runs on a view and the view retrieves about 1 million records. My stored procedure gets 309 records.

We got this data only 2 days back and my stored procedure was taking 25 sec - 1 minute to retrieve the records until last night and suddenly it seemed to be taking about 25 minutes to get the results, since then.

RAM on the server has been increased to see if this might increase the performance, but that has no impact. Below is my base query. Can someone please look into this and let me know how performance can be improved.

```
DECLARE @ReportStartDate DATETIME,
        @ReportEndDate DATETIME, 
        @IsInternalUser INT, 
        @UserId INT, 
        @FFY INT

SET @UserId = 2
SET @FFY = -1
SET @Quarter = -1

/*  Checks if the user is a Internal user or external user */
SELECT @IsInternalUser = rpt.ufn_IsInternalUser(@UserId)

/*Get reporting dates */
SELECT 
    @ReportStartDate = (CASE WHEN MIN(FromDate) >= GETDATE() 
                               THEN GETDATE() 
                               ELSE MIN(FromDate) END), 
    @ReportEndDate = (CASE WHEN MAX(ToDate) >= GETDATE() 
                             THEN GETDATE() 
                             ELSE MAX(ToDate) END) 
FROM 
    rpt.FFYDate      
WHERE 
    FFY = (CASE WHEN @FFY = -1 THEN FFY ELSE @FFY END) 
    AND QuarterNumber = (CASE WHEN @Quarter = -1 THEN QuarterNumber ELSE @Quarter END)

/*Final Query*/
SELECT 
    LC.AwardIdentifier, LC.ProgramName, LC.AwardStartDate, 
    LC.AwardEndDate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT LC.ClientID), LC.RecipientName, LC.ServiceTarget,
    (CASE 
       WHEN (@ReportStartDate >= LC.AwardStartDate AND @ReportEndDate <= LC.AwardEndDate) THEN ((DATEDIFF(MONTH, @ReportStartDate, @ReportEndDate)) * LC.ServiceTarget / (DATEDIFF(Month, LC.AwardStartDate, LC.AwardEndDate))) --WITHIN AWARD DATES                    
       WHEN (@ReportStartDate <= LC.AwardStartDate AND @ReportEndDate <= LC.AwardEndDate) THEN ((DATEDIFF(MONTH, LC.AwardStartDate, @ReportEndDate))  * LC.ServiceTarget / (DATEDIFF(Month, LC.AwardStartDate, LC.AwardEndDate))) --OVERLAP WITH AWARD DATES                    
       ELSE 0
    END) AS ClientTarget
FROM    
    rpt.VwCSATIntakeCoverageReport_Legacy LC
LEFT JOIN 
    UserRoleEntity URE ON URE.EntityId = (CASE WHEN ure.EntityTypeCode = 'AWARD' THEN LC.AwardID WHEN ure.EntityTypeCode ='SITEAWARD' THEN LC.SiteAwardId END) 
LEFT JOIN 
    CDPUserRole UR ON URE.UserRoleId = UR.Id AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId
WHERE 
    (LC.InterviewDate BETWEEN @ReportStartDate AND @ReportEndDate) 
    AND (@IsInternalUser = 1 -- Interanl User
         OR (UR.CDPUserId = @UserId AND UR.ID IS NOT NULL)) -- External User
GROUP BY 
    LC.AwardIdentifier, LC.ProgramName, LC.AwardStartDate, 
    LC.AwardEndDate, LC.RecipientName, LC.ServiceTarget
```

My tech lead looked into this and said that the problem might be with `COUNT(DISTINCT LC.ClientID)` and the resulting group by and asked me to comment that out (and add a "distinct" to the top select. I tried adding a `SELECT` statement on top of my final select query, and tried doing `COUNT(DISTINCT LC.ClientID)` on top, but the performance hasn't changed.

This needs to go into production this week and any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What does the execution plan show as the bottleneck?

Comment: I'd possibly look into parameter sniffing. It's possible that the query plan that was cached is terrible for what you are running now.  What indexes, if any, do you have on the tables?

Answer (score 0):

First, run the query execution plan on the stored procedure. Look for any word than says scan instead of seek.  Also, the query execution plan should recommend any missing indexes.  Once you've done this, add this to the top of your code for some additional information:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

This will show you the cost of hitting each table within your query and you can determine which one of your tables is slowing you down.

As for the COUNT(DISTINCT fieldname) , you can try using a CTE to grab the specific pool of ClientID's you want and inner join onto the CTE on ClientID, then count that number. Run an query execution plan and take a look at the statistics and let me know what you find.

Comment: I ran this. But I do not know how to decode this information.

Comment: SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON
GO

SET FMTONLY ON
GO

SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON


EXEC @return_value = [rpt].[usp_IntakeCoverageReport]

SET FMTONLY OFF
GO
SET SHOWPLAN_ALL OFF
GO

Comment: you're looking for large IO numbers. If a table is doing a heap scan or a logical scan for over 500,000 -1,000,000 IO, you may have a performance issue.  Did the query execution tab suggest any indexes?